# Infinite Sphere is connected but not compact

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$: Space of sequences $(x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of real numbers such that at most finitrly many of $x_i$'s are nonzero
Embed $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ via $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \to (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,0)$. Then $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}=\cup_n\mathbb{R}^n$

Define a topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ by declaring that a set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is closed iff $C \cap \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^n}$ for every $n$.

Let $S^\infty=\cup_{n}S^n$. Show that $S^\infty$ is connected but not compact.

Suppose that $S^{\infty}=C \cup D$ where $C$ and $D$ are two disjoint closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. Then $S^m=(S^m\cap C)\cup (S^m \cap D)$. Since $C$ and $D$ are closed in $\mathbb{R^{\infty}}$, $C\cap \mathbb{R}^m$ and $D \cap \mathbb{R}^m$ are closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

So $S^m=(S^m \cap C \cap \mathbb{R}^m) \cup (S^m \cap D \cap \mathbb{R^m})$ can be written as a disjoint union of closed sets implying that $S^m$ is not connected which is a contradiction.

Let $A_n=B_n(0,r)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $r \gt 1$ .Then $A_n$ is open and $S^{\infty}=\cup_n A_n$. But this cover doesn't have a finite subcover.

Is this alright?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: This might work: let $P_n=(0,0,\cdots,0,0,1)\in S^n\subset\Bbb R^n$. Seems to me that the sequence of points $\{P_n\}$ doesn’t have an accumulation point in $S^\infty$.

Comment: @Lubin is this space metrizable?

Comment: There is no metric on it.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not metrizable. If it is, then Lubin's comment works pretty well as an answer. If not, I think a slight modification should still work.

Comment: I was thinking of making an open cover of balls of radius 1.5

Comment: @Jason What I meant was, the question doesn't mention of a metric. Probably it wants me to do without the use of it.

Comment: Again, you're misunderstanding what I mean. If this topology is given by some metric, then compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness. It doesn't matter what the metric is, but if one exists then we can use that result and Lusin's comment to conclude. If there is no such metric, this equivalence no longer necessarily holds, so we will need to be a little more careful.

Comment: @Jason I understood what you meant.

Comment: This space is not metrizable. A connected CW-complex is metrizable if and only if it is locally compact, which in turn holds if and only if each point has a neighbourhood that meets only finitely many cells. It is not hard to check this for $S^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=\{e_n:n\ge1\}$ where $e_n=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$, the $1$ being in the $n^\text{th}$ position. Then $B\cap\mathbb R^n=\{e_k:1\le k\le n\}$ which is closed, hence $B$ is closed. Clearly $B\subset S^\infty$, so it suffices to show $B$ is not compact. Let $U_n=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots):|x_n-1|<\frac12\}$. Then $U_n^c=\{x:|x_n-1|\ge\frac12\}$ which is clearly closed, so $U_n$ is open. Moreover, $e_n\in U_m$ if and only if $n=m$, so $\{U_n\}$ is a cover of $B$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: Will my argument work??

Comment: I’m not sure what your $A_n$ is: these sets don’t look open in the total union.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another fun proof. Consider the map

$$ f \colon S^{\infty} \to \mathbb{R} $$

$$ (x_0,x_1,\ldots) \mapsto \sum n x_n $$

This map is well defined since any element of $S^{\infty}$ has only a finite number of nonzero $x_i$. And it is continuous because the restriction to each $S^n$ is continuous. The images of the points $(0,\ldots,0,1,0, \ldots)$ and $(0,\ldots,0,-1,0, \ldots)$ are precisely the integers and so all the integers belong to the image. Since the map is continuous, it must be surjective. But $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, so $S^{\infty}$ can not be compact.

Comment: This looks good to me!